# Regex - Match capital, simple string after specific character

Tags: regex

I have following string :

```
step_User_Save_action_Details
```

I checking capital or simple letter follows after each underscore symbol, but not all capital..

Example:

`step_User_Save_Action_Details` - Should return `False`

`step_user_save_Action_Details` - Should return `True`

`step_user_save_action_details` - Should return `True`

try with this but seems to be its not the catching it

```
\bstep(?:_[a-z][a-zA-Z]*)+\b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead based regex:

```
/\bstep(?!(?:_[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)+\b)(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)+\b/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG0lA1/2)

`(?!(?:_[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)+\b)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if underscore are all immediately followed by a capital letters.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i expected

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?  Can't you just use

```
/_[a-z]/
```

(Match any string that contains a lowercase letter after an underscore).